# Different columns select for each object in linq

Tags: linq

my object model is:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJAul.png)

I want to have a select on "Staff" table based on the definition access level in "TrusteeAccess" Table per user. In addition, the columns of the selected rows in "Staff" table are set according to "TrusteeAccessFields". In other words, if there isn't row in "TrusteeAccessFields" Table, the value of the column in "Staff" table is null.

```
    public IEnumerable<StaffInfo> GetByUserAccess(User user)
    {
        IEnumerable<TrusteeAccess> trusteeAccsses = db.TrusteeAccesses.Where(ta => ta.UserId == user.UserId);
        var results = db.StaffInfo.Where(s => trusteeAccsses.Any(t => t.StaffInfoId == s.StaffInfoId)).Select(/* Different Columns */).ToList();
        return results;
    }
```

Note1: For each column name in "Staff" Table, there is an object in "TrusteeAccessFields" Table.
Note2: The number of columns in "Staff" Table is large.

what is that linq query per user?

Comment: What does "based on" mean in query/programming terms? It is much more helpful if you provide code rather than pictures. What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What database provider (if any)?

Comment: @NetMage I added code in my question. By "based on" I mean that if the "Trusted Access" table returns the object(s), I want to select different columns in the "Staff" table per object. I use E.F 6.4.4.

Comment: What C# type do you expect `results` to be?

Comment: Collection of my class(StaffInfo).

Comment: With only the properties corresponding to the desired columns populated with values?

Comment: yes. i want exactly that.